# Lines clip when overlapping meshs

Tags: opengl

I am rendering lines at the same position as a mesh and when the lines are right on top of the mesh I get an effect where the lines start to clip and parts of them disappear, especially when moving around.
What I eventually have to do is something like the screenshot below, move the lines off the mesh a little bit in order to get rid of that effect. Does anyone have any ideas on how I can render the lines so that they are right on the mesh without parts of it disappearing?

[image]

Comment: Are you using `glPolygonOffset()`?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, are these lines really lines? Or are they the mesh drawn a second time with `glPolygonMode (GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINES)`? In either case, the problem is that the filled polygons and your lines are generating (roughly) the same depths and passing/failing the depth test is not working like you want.

The solution is to add a very slight depth offset to one of the primitives, and the easiest way to do this is to use `glPolygonOffset (...)`. But it is worth mentioning that this only works for filled primitives (e.g. `GL_POLYGON`, `GL_QUADS`, `GL_TRIANGLES`) and not `GL_LINES` or `GL_POINTS`.

---

If it is the same mesh drawn twice, on the second pass you can do something like this:

```
glPolygonOffset (-0.1f, -1.0f);
glEnable        (GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_LINE);

   ... Draw Mesh Second Time

glDisable       (GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_LINE);
```

Otherwise, you will need to apply the depth offset when you draw the (**solid**) mesh the first time:

```
glPolygonOffset (0.1f, 1.0f);
glEnable        (GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);

  ... Draw Mesh

glDisable       (GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);

... Draw Lines
```

You may need to tweak the values used for `glPolygonOffset (...)`, it depends on a number of factors including depth buffer precision and the implementation. Generally the second parameter is going to be more important, it is a constant offset applied to the depth. The first factor varies according to the change in depth (e.g. angle).

Comment: thank you, I did not know polygon offset existed and it worked very well.